# Spring-Boot: Web-Filter for Redirection

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlet-filters

I am having a filter. It should redirect to /b if /a is requested.

```
public class WebFilter extends GenericFilterBean
{ 
 @Override
 public void doFilter (ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
 {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    String path = req.getRequestURI ().toString ();

    if (path.equals ("/a") == true)
    {
        System.out.println ("FILTER: a -> b");
        res.reset ();
        res.resetBuffer();
        res.sendRedirect ("b");
    }

    chain.doFilter (req, res);
  }
}
```

Here is the handler for the content.

```
@Component
@Controller
@RequestMapping ("/")
public class WebHandler
{

 @RequestMapping ("/a")
 public String a ()
 {
    System.out.println ("a");
    return "a"; // point to a.jsp
 }

 @RequestMapping ("/b")
 public String b (HttpSession ses)
 {
     System.out.println ("b");
     return "b"; // point to b.jsp
 }
}
```

If I request /a in a browser, then that is the output.

```
FILTER: a -> b
IN a
IN b
```

Why is method a called? 
I would expect only b because I redirect in doFilter from a to b.
How can I make that happen?

Comment: Are you using spring security?

Comment: No, to that I am aware of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So you are actually doing a redirect although it seems you just want to direct the request to a different controller mapping.

```
    res.sendRedirect ("b");
```

Just changes the response code to `302` and adds a `location` field, you will still hit the first controller, which is why you still see `a` in the logs.
The browser then acknowledges this redirect directive and will send a second request for `/b`.

One way to achieve what you appear to want would be to create a new Request from the submitted one, and simply override the `getRequestUri()` method.

```
    @Override
    public void doFilter (ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        String path = req.getRequestURI();


        if (path.equals("/a")) {
            req = new HttpServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request) {
                @Override
                public String getRequestURI() {
                    return "/b";
                }
            };
        }

        chain.doFilter (req, res);
    }
```

This is then passed to the filter chain and everything continues as though that were the original request